# List Tabs required attribute

Tags: docusignapi

It doesn't appear that the Rest 2.0 API returns the required attribute for a list tab. In my example, the tab on my document *is* required, but the JSON returned from the API doesn't contain the required attribute:

```
"listTabs": [
    {
      "listItems": [
        {
          "text": "Steve",
          "value": "Steve",
          "selected": "true"
        },
        {
          "text": "John",
          "value": "John",
          "selected": "false"
        },
        {
          "text": "Alexa",
          "value": "Alexa",
          "selected": "false"
        }
      ],
      "value": "Alexa",
      "width": 77,
      "shared": "false",
      "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
      "tabLabel": "Rep",
      "font": "arial",
      "fontSize": "size11",
      "documentId": "1",
      "recipientId": "86d68ea3-9aee-470a-8aed-53846ca5587d",
      "pageNumber": "1",
      "xPosition": "283",
      "yPosition": "269",
      "tabId": "e4ddc5ca-3670-417e-b4ba-ef0ce38270d1"
    }
  ]
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a bug here?  Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to reproduce this issue, and it seems like a bug to me. If the required property is set to **true** for a Drop Down list, you should be seeing `"required": "true"` in the "GET Recipients (with tabs)" API response body.  Perhaps someone from DocuSign can chime in here to either confirm the bug, or explain the behavior.